# [SyncVar]s in Unity with client authority

Tags: unity, synchronization, unet

I'm making an networked RTS in Unity, and I have a problem with syncing a boolean on a non-player object. I create the object (which is a boat) using `SpawnWithClientAuthority()` on the server, with the boat's owner as the player argument.

From my knowledge of `SpawnWithClientAuthority()`, it would seem that I could then change the boat's `SyncVar`s from the client and they would be reflected on other clients, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I do have `Local Player Authority` checked on the boat's `NetworkIdentity`. What's even more interesting is that the change works if it occurs on the Host's client, whereas it doesn't if it's on the remote client.